# Which document I can find bluetooth HCI event code meaning?

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

While I was searching how to find Bluetooth HCI event code meaning, I found the link below.
[Raspberry Pi Bluetooth HCI Event Code Meaning](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111740/raspberry-pi-bluetooth-hci-event-code-meaning?newreg=ae8e1410a4d54e9991b18011957dbec3)

In this post, Section 7.8 Part E, Vol 4 and Section 7.7.14, Part E Vol 4 are mentioned.
But I still don't know which document include this sections.
I downloaded Core_v5.4.pdf but it does not have those sections.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the easiest document to read, but those sections do appear to be in there. I downloaded it from https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-4/

[image]

[image]

[image]